# Virtual printer whith local port as file and cyrillic text

Tags: windows, printer

I create local port and virtual printer by command:

```
Add-PrinterPort -Name "D:\MyTestPrinter.txt"
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "MyTestPrinter" /r "D:\MyTestPrinter.txt" /m "Generic / Text Only"
```

All create fine, when I try print from notepad I get "MyTestPrinter" in print list and info add to `D:\MyTestPrinter.txt`, but if I print some cyrillic I get "`......`".

How confirm virtual printer to work with cyrillic?

Comment: I provided a possible answer to your other question before I saw this one. Having seen this one. I realise that's probably irrelevant. Can you explain what you are trying to do (where does the print job come from, and where is it going)?

Answer (score 0):

A 'Generic (Text-only)' print driver will support all ASCII characters.

However, characters of a value of Hex "7E" (decimal 127) or greater are
not be supported by the 'Generic (Text-only)' driver.

Comment: and it are there ways to create a virtual printer to print Cyril to a file?

Comment: Only if you control the driver, which you don't in this case.

Comment: ok... and how to control the driver? maybe it possibly to download any driver?

Comment: If it's possible, I haven't heard of it.